# Easy lazy loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have successfully implemented lazy loading using the class `UIImageView+WebCache.h`.
Is there any easy method for lazy loading without using the class `UIImageView+WebCache.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the images in a UIWebView. For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"ID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

            UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

            NSLog(@"URL=%@",[arrayURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [webView loadRequest:req];
            webView.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:webView];

        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to spoil your answer, but I see two potential problems: 1. The UIWebView is only added to cells that are *newly allocated*, but not to cells that are *reused*. 2. `loadRequest` works asynchronously, so when the request is finished, the cell might already have been *reused* for a different row.